# How to check if copy constructor is noexcept without using type_traits?

Tags: c++, type-traits

After some experimenting I've managed to write a piece of code that will check whether the move constructor of a class is noexcept (without using type_traits; this is just an exercise):

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << noexcept(Widget(std::declval<Widget>())) << std::endl;
```

The declval function "returns" Widget&&, so the whole expression is a move constructor call. But how to achieve something similar for the copy constructor?

Comment: you could `*static_cast<Widget>(nullptr)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::declval<Widget&>()`. Reference collapsing will turn `T&& &` into `T&`:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << noexcept(Widget(std::declval<Widget&>())) << std::endl;
//                                                          ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Anyway, I wonder how to write a similar check for copying = operator? :)

Comment: @BarbedWire `noexcept(declval<Widget&>() = declval<Widget const&>())`

Answer (score 2):

You could declare your own `declval`-like function:

```
template< class T >
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type mydeclval() noexcept;

//outputs true if the copy constructor is declared noexcept
std::cout << std::boolalpha << noexcept(Widget(mydeclval<Widget>())) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Oh, I've just been doing almost the same thing but forgot to add noexcept to mydeclval itself and wondered why it doesn't work :D Thanks!

Comment: Waaaaait a second... but the original declval is not declared as noexcept! So why does it work for my code?

Comment: @rubix_addict It is declared noexcept: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry. I quickly looked at declval signature on cppreference and didn't realize that there is "noexcept specification" further in the text.